# Confluent Kafka - Lowest read offset

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

When consuming from a non-compacted topic, how can I determine the earliest available offset on the topic? In my case the message retention is 7 days. Low watermark does not help in this case because it is 0 and of course not what I am looking for. Is there any alternative to

```
    get_watermark_offsets
```

in order to get the earliest available offset to be consumed?

Answer (score 0):

That function is correct. A topic can hold data for longer than the retention time if there are no closed segments within that time period.